# User is denied access when running a query

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

my vb.net code is supposed to connect to my database. It did this successfully until I added a query to check if the username and password existed. After adding this, the user is denied access whilst still using the same password. What could be the cause of this? Code:

```
MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()

    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=;" _
    & "user id=;" _
    & "password=;" _
    & "database="

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) From tableUser WHERE Username=" & TextBox1.Text & " AND Password=" & TextBox2.Text
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = MysqlConn
            result = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        End Using
        MysqlConn.Close()
        If (result < 1) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please make sure you have typed valid credentials!")
        ElseIf result = 1 Then
            Dim form As New Form2
            form.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Connection to the database has been lost. Please try again later.")
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: *Please* look into **using parameterized queries**.  And *stop storing passwords as plain text in your database!*  Your code is just begging for [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) to come take a visit.

Comment: there's not really enough info here. At what point is the user denied access, precisely? When you run the next query? Post the exact error message and the code where it occurs. And the comments above re security and SQL injection are also very valid, btw

Comment: Yeah I know about storing them in plain text, this is purely as a test :)

Comment: Sugest you do some reading about database security and then your question will be answered most likely.

Comment: When you say "the user is denied access", do you mean `result < 1`?

Comment: Unless you're quoting your `TextBox` values, there's no way your query will work.  Using parameterized queries not only protects against SQL Injection, but it also protects against all of the pitfalls of using concatenated SQL.  Switching now might even solve your issue.

Comment: Unless all logins and passwords are numeric. :p

Comment: did you try `result = 0` :)

Comment: The program now works fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Matt142 Please show us the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code , i just wrote it , hope it helps ,just change it to your needs.

```
Private Sub login()
    conn = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=batabase;port=3307"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then


        MessageBox.Show("Please enter usename ! ", "Enter username")
        Exit Sub

    End If
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("Please enter password", "Enter password")
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Try


        conn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from db.users where user='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and password='" & TextBox2.Text & "' "
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, conn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        Dim count As Integer

        count = 0
        While READER.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While

        If count = 1 Then

            Form.Show()
            Me.Hide()

        ElseIf count > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("The username is already in use!")
        Else
            MsgBox("Error , please try again ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If




        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Change the database name user name to your needs and it will work !

just add the login() in your login button on your form !!!
or enter this code on your button without the Private Sub login()